# MVC RedirectToAction is not working properly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

In one of my controllers, I do have a return that looks like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("AdministerFiles/ViewDataFiles?catid=14");
```

but when it renders the result to the browser the string becomes this one:

```
AdministerFiles/AdministerFiles/ViewDataFiles%3fcatid%3d14
```

how can I solve this ? thanks .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need the action as the parameter (along with the route data):

```
return RedirectToAction("ViewDataFiles", new { catid = 14 });
```

If you want to specify the controller as well (it defaults to the current controller), then you can do it like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("ViewDataFiles", "AdministerFiles", new { catid = 14 });
```

Comment: +1. And if you even want to redirect over areas, you can do `return RedirectToAction("actionName", "controllerName", new {area = "areaName"})` :)

Comment: And there is a difference between administer and administrator :P (for the op, i realise this answer is based off what the op called them and as such isnt wrong)