# AspNetCore MVC - return RedirectToAction is getting ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an action as below:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult SendEmailVerificationCode(int userId)
{
    SpaceUser user = userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId).Result;
    bool taskComleted = SendEmailVerificationLink(userId).IsCompleted;
    if (taskComleted)
    {
        AddToErrorData(InfoMessages.EmailVerificationLinkSent_Params, user.Email);
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("EmailNotConfirmed", new { userId = user.Id });
    }
}
```

When I make the code jump into the else block (when debugging) it makes the redirection to `EmailNotConfirmed` action, which is in the same controller. But it doesn't redirect to `HomeController`'s `Index` action. Instead, the browser stays at `Account/SendEmailVerificationCode` and displays a blank page.

`HomeController.Index` is as below:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

I tried these:

- In the beginning `SendEmailVerificationCode` action was async but `HomeController.Index` wasn't. So I declared them both as async.
- Then I deleted the `async` declaration from both of them.
- I tried `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");`.
- `SendEmailVerificationCode` had `HttpPost` attribute; I changed it to `HttpGet`.

How can I make the redirection to an action in a different Controller?
Any help would be appreciated.

P.S.: I have been doing research about this issue for a while now and I've read the solutions for questions such as:
[MVC RedirectToAction is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976797/mvc-redirecttoaction-is-not-working-properly)
[RedirectToAction gets ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34261205/redirecttoaction-gets-ignored)

But none of these or the questions regarding the action not being redirected after an ajax request have helped me.

Thanks.

Comment: Tried to add a new Route in `Startup.cs` as `routes.MapRoute("MainIndex", "{controller}/{action}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });` And make redirection by: `return RedirectToRoute("MainIndex");` But it didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured the problem by adding some logging into the application. It turns out that the actual problem was being hidden.

I was using TempData to store the customized error messages and I was utilizing it via the `AddToErrorData` function I had displayed in the question.

In AspNetCore, `Serializable` attribute has disappeared along with `ISerializable` interface. Therefore, TempData was unable to serialize my custom `IList` object list.

When I changed the `TempData[ConstantParameters.ErrorData] = _errorData;` to `TempData[ConstantParameters.ErrorData] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_errorData);` the redirection problem was solved.

For reference: I also had to change the TempData retrieving line as: `_errorData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ErrorDataList>(TempData[ConstantParameters.ErrorData].ToString());`

Comment: It pains me to see this type of problem and the cause is utterly hidden and unrelated. Another foundational problem with modern Microsoft products. They are getting all too common.